# ¿Cómo abro un activity dependiendo de preferencias?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo que hacer una aplicación Android, que en su primer uso tiene que lanzar un activity de creación de contraseña. A partir de ahí, cada vez que la abras, debe detectar que ya has creado esa contraseña y debe pedirla (esto es otra ventana).

No sé como hacer eso. Sé cómo guardar la password que ha metido como SharedPreferences para luego comprobarla con la que el usuario ponga cuando entre, pero no consigo lanzar una ventana u otra dependiendo de si hay password creada o no.

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: Esta bien explicado pero deberías aportar el código que has probado hasta el momento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bienvenido a `stackoverflow`, lo que necesitas hacer es una clase que se ejecute de primero al momento que se abra la `app`, seria algo como esto, ejemplo:

```
public class ValidateIn extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // Acá obtienes las preferencias que tienes, y haces la respectiva validación
        // ejemplo

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("User", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String getpassword = preferences.getString("password", null);

        if (getpassword!=null{
            // intent, o realizar la accion que necesites si consigue la contraseña
        } else {
            // intent, o realizar la accion que necesites si no consigue la contraseña
          }
}
```

Para que esta clase se ejecute primero al abrir la `app`, lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:

En tu `AndroidManifest.xml` en este apartado:

```
<application
        android:name=".ValidateIn" <!-- agregas el directorio de la clase acá "Nombre" -->
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
         ......
         ......
         ......
         </application>
```

De esta forma esa clase sera la primera en ejecutarse al momento de abrir la `app` y acá decides que mostrar según la validación que se haga.

Comment: Por favor hazme saber si te funciona lo que deseas hacer de esta manera @Aldruxx , saludos

Comment: Lo primero, muchas gracias, he entendido perfectamente lo que decías, ya he planteado las cosas y funciona como quería.

Comment: @Aldruxx excelente, que bueno que te funcionara :)

Comment: Hola, disculpen pero tengo mismo problema, excepto que mi logeo esta en un fragmento y quiero utilizar preferencia, utilizo un spinner que selecciona una IP de un servidor que me conecto y un switch que hace correr al hilo, los demás campos si lo guarda excepto el spinner, igual sigue perdiendose la información. Por favor ayuda, lo necesito.